# Por qué no carga mis eventos de un archivo externo en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Encontré una pregunta en ingles acerca de un problema de métodos pero ninguno en español y  referente al titulo que menciono. Espero que resuelvan algunas dudas.

Este es un archivo `app.js` externo ubicado entre los`<head><script src="app.js"></scritp></head>` que lo único que hace es pintar un "Hola Mundo" al `index.html` principal por medio de una acción del click.

```
  document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Hello World";});
```

Al momento de cargar(<kbd>F5</kbd>) la pagina se observa un error en consola de Chrome:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

y algo parecido en Firefox:

> `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`

Answer (score 1):

Bueno este error se produce por el solo hecho de esperar una acción del elemento indicado (DOM).

Esto se puede solucionar de dos maneras (*aún de existir otras*) :

### Solución 01

```
  window.onload=function(){
     document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", function(){
     document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Hello World";
  }
```

Este método hace que cargue la ventana de nuestro `index.html` principal (BOM) luego accione los métodos y elementos por medio de la función anónima.

### Solución 02

Otra forma es colocar nuestro archivo externo `app.js` en el `<body><script src="app.js"></script></body>` del HTML. Pues de forma directa 
  identificará el elemento dentro del DOM.

Answer (score 0):

El error te sale por que aún no se ha creado el botón que estás buscando `getElementById("boton")` una forma de solucionarlo de forma sencilla es que cargues el archivo javascript justo antes de cerrar el `body`

```
<body>
  <button id="boton"></button>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```